# Create divs with row size as 3 and column to be of size N

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I want to display divs so that it can be horizontally scrolled. I have created a display flex container but I am not sure what else do I need to do so that the boxes are aligned to the left.

[Here is the demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qyssuh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

```
.container {
  height: 95px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

The uncommented code works fine. The momement I comment the cols, I get extra spacing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `align-content` and `justify-content` properties allow you to choose where items in the flexbox appear. I suggest you look them up (for example [on CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) to understand how they work. In this case setting `align-content: flex-start;` to the `.container` object will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?: [HERE](https://angular-ivy-ywcfrb.stackblitz.io)

[image]

```
.container {
  height: 95px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}
```

Comment: Hello, please check the updated code. I have added an image